# Details summary h4 hover color

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

I am trying to color the h4 text inside a details summary upon hover, but the color change only takes effect when hovering DIRECTLY OVER the actual h4 text, how can I modify my CSS to change the h4 text color when hovering over other parts of the summary bar?

[Codepen - actual code starts @ line 62](https://codepen.io/chad_/pen/KKZZdBw) (lines 1-59 are just setting environment styles so that my code is predictably transferable to my theme)

```
.accordion-button:not([open]) h4:hover,
.accordion-button:not([open]) h4:focus {
  color: var(--color-button-text);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need move `:hover` to the parent element:

```
.accordion-button:not([open]):hover h4,
.accordion-button:not([open]):focus h4 {
  color: var(--color-button-text);
}
```